# The part of zipper slider which you grasp to pull

Tags: word-request, nouns

What's the name of the part of the zipper you grasp in order to unzip the zipper - specifically, the small dangling part that sometimes snaps off if the zipper is poor quality, making you unable to open or close it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Image of zipper parts]
http://www.stanssewingsupplies.com/catalogs/store.asp?pid=252488

The part you grasp is called the **zipper pull**. The strings sometimes added to the tab are also called zipper pulls. To help with questions like this in the future I found the results by searching for "zipper parts".

Comment: Interesting question and an interesting answer.  Personally, I had no idea what it was called.  Lesson learned and thank you.  So, here's an example of how this is typically used:  "My zipper pull got bent."  "What the heck is a zipper pull?"  "Oh, it's the thingie that you pull on when you're zipping the zipper."  :)